# Finding the Laurent Series for $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ for $0<|z|<2\pi$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laurent-series

Since $\left|\dfrac{1}{e^z}\right|<1$ I figured I could rewrite the given function into a geometric series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(e^z)^n}$$

But this seems to be way off the mark. I think I am confused about when one is supposed to rewrite the expressions into series. I guess this expression above isn't correct because I need to express $e^z$ into a series. I can't really make sense of how to do that though.

Should I use $\displaystyle e^z=1+\frac{z}{1!}+\frac{z^2}{2!}+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$

giving

$$\frac{1}{e^z-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^j}{j!})^n}$$

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Have you tried Cauchy's differentiation theorem?

Comment: Does that even work, I mean it has a hole in $z=0$. Should I rewrite it as two integrals: $$\int_{|z|=2\pi}f(z)dz-\int_{\epsilon}f(z)dz$$ or something?

Comment: Part of the reason that the geometric series idea doesn't work so well is that your expansion is best where $e^z$ is small - i.e. where $\Re{z}$ is large. Your expansion is for $z\approx0$, so your techniques should make use of approximations that hold in that region.

Comment: If you look through the proof of Cauchy's differentiation theorem, it picks out the $(-1)^{\text{th}}$ power in the Laurent series (that's why you divide by powers of $z$).  Since the only hole in this case is at $z=0$, you're actually getting the residues at that point (which are coefficients of the power series expansion).

Comment: So you mean that for the differential formula:

$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z_0}d\xi$$ 

I set $z_0 = 1$ but then what do i do with $\xi$? We haven't studied residues yet.

Comment: @πr8 That's interesting I wasn't aware of that. What other methods for approximations are you referring to?

Comment: @StrangeBrew It's most noticeable when you're finding series expansions for composite functions, I'd say - approximations are (generally) most accurate when you're dealing with small quantities, so if you're expanding something in powers, you want to make those powers small. E.g. writing $\frac{1}{e^z-1}=\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{e^z-1-z}{z}\right)}$, you can use $\frac{e^z-1-z}{z}\approx \frac{1}{2}z$ for $z\approx0$ and $\frac{1}{1+u}\approx 1-u$ for $u\approx0$ to see that $\frac{1}{e^z-1}\approx \frac{1}{z}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}z\right)$ for $z\approx0$.

Comment: @StrangeBrew [ran out of space above] and naturally, taking more and more terms in the expansions of $\frac{e^z-1-z}{z}$ and $\frac{1}{1+u}$ will let you gain greater accuracy. The key observation is that if you're doing any kind of expansion around $z\approx0$, you want your terms to be relevant to the location $z\approx0$.

Answer (score 6):

One may observe that $\displaystyle  z \to \frac{z}{e^z-1}$ is analytic in $0<|z|<2\pi$, then it admits a power series expansion
$$
\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n\frac{z^n}{n!}, \quad 0<|z|<2\pi, \tag1
$$ with $b_0=1$, $b_1=-1/2$.

Then, multiplying $(1)$ by $\displaystyle e^z$,
$$
\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k\frac{z^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^m}{m!}\right)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}e^z=z+\frac{z}{e^z-1}=z+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n\frac{z^n}{n!},\tag2
$$ using the Cauchy product, one gets
$$
b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}b_k, \quad n>1, \quad b_0=1,\, b_1=-1/2,\tag3
$$ but from $(3)$ one sees that these are just the standard [Bernoulli numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html): $B_n$.

Finally, we have

> $$
> \frac1{e^z-1}=\frac1z-\frac12+\frac{z}{12}+\cdots=\frac1z+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}B_{n+1}\frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}, \quad 0<|z|<2\pi. \tag4
> $$

Comment: That's interesting, however I've never seen anything like that solution before. How do you find $$\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n\frac{z^n}{n!}?$$

Comment: I just recognized the Bernoulli numbers where hidden in the Laurent series expansion, that's why I've chosen an exponential generating function, which is equivalent to the ordinary generating function. Thanks.

Comment: While I recognize that you've solved the question I don't know how to apply your solution. Since there has been no mention of Bernoulli numbers numbers in my coursebook I think there must be another method.

Answer (score 2):

Note: If you proceed with the geometric series approach, you find (formally) that:

$$\frac{1}{e^z-1}=\sum_{n\ge1}e^{-nz}=\sum_{n\ge1}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^kn^kz^k}{k!}=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^kz^k}{k!}\sum_{n\ge1}n^k$$

The term at the end, $\sum_{n\ge1}n^k$, is obviously infinite and divergent. That being said, some treatments allow us to assign value to these sums in some sense. By noting the definition of the Riemann zeta function, we can write $\sum_{n\ge1}n^k=\zeta(-k)$.

What is somewhat surprising is that if we compute the coefficients of the expansion for $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ and compare them to these divergent sums, they agree with the results obtained by analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function, that is, that all this haphazard symbolic manipulation turns out to be (at least partially) vindicated.

A cute consequence of this is that because $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ is (nearly) an odd function, the "value" of $\sum_{n\ge1}n^k$ is $=0$ for all even $k\ge2$.